# Can you mix server brands in a quorum?

Tags: networking, server, virtual-machine, quorum

In theory, could we link an HP, a Dell and an IBM in a quorum using vmware esxi? As long as they are configured and can communicate it should work fine. My IBM might not work but at least HP and Dell should work.

I'm in a debate with someone that swear up and down that he can only quorum HP with HP or the whole thing will fall apart. He's said some other things that makes me question his skill and motives but I don't have all the knowledge myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can Quorum anything with anything.
It does not relate to the vendor what so ever. In reality, operating systems are what get connected and not the actual hardware.